# Can someone help me understand what this address is? It says its private but has a lot of weird transactions. I am trying to track a scammer

Tags: ether, etherscan, myetherwallet, mixers

I am tracking a scammer and I need to figure something out, just to be sure. For example https://bloxy.info/ is telling me this address 0xc94ebb328ac25b95db0e0aa968371885fa516215 is a a regular address of wallet , there were no smart contract calls from this address but it has Internal txn.It has a lot of transactions. Based on my observation, the scammer circulates around a lot of eth, maybe using bots or is this ETH mixer? I dont know how that works/looks. He sends small transactions, most of the time, and then they go to a few addresses, then come back and in between he send other, usually larger transactions that lead to, in many cases, exchanges. Any advice? Thanks.

Comment: It's likely an exchange hot wallet or similar.

Comment: is there a way to see of which one?

Comment: btw it says it is regular address wallet, this means it belongs to one user?

Comment: Which private intellgence like https://nansen.ai/ you get better labelling of addresses.

Answer (score 0):

Its from a casino website, roobet.com